# Кластеризация: "TypeError: type other than float or double not supported"

Tags: python, python-2.x, кластеризация

Подскажите пожалуйста почему питон выдает ошибку и как ее исправить!

Заранее большое спасибо!

[image]

Comment: Синим по белому же пишет, что `feauteres` должен быть массивом вещественных чисел, а не целых.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: большое спасибо за комментарии, все учту:)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже заметили коллеги `kmeans` ожидает вещественные, а не целые числа.

Преобразование можно сделать "на лету", используя `array.astype(float)`:

```
In [20]: kmeans(features.astype(float), b)
Out[20]:
(array([[ 12. ],
        [  2. ],
        [  8.5],
        [  5.5]]), 0.5)
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста почему  kmeans не изменяет исходные элементы списка, а не просто группирует их?

Comment: @Амир, `kmeans` по определению возвращает список центроидов...

Comment: а как получить сами элементы?

Comment: @Амир, мне кажется я [ответил на это в другом вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678343/211923)