# Разбиение списка на несколько

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

дан список `[11,12,13,15,16,17,19]`. Необходимо разбить его на непрерывные группы, например `[11,12,13]`, `[15,16,17]`, `[19]` вот так в этом случае. Все числа идут по возрастанию. 
Логика действия понятна: ищем разницу между соседними элементами, если она единица, то их в одну группу, если нет, в другую. Не понятно как заранее определить количество групп.
Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2154409/5741205

Comment: Вы ищете решение для "чистого" Python или можно использовать библиотеки типа Numpy/SciPy/Pandas?

Comment: с использованием библиотек

Answer (score 2):

Без использования библиотек:

```
def split(l):
    res = [[l[0]]]
    last = l[0]
    for i in l[1:]:
        if i - last == 1:
            res[-1].append(i)
        else:
            res.append([i])
        last = i
    return res


print split([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14])
```

[[1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [8, 9], [11], [13, 14]]

Примечание: список должен состоять из чисел, и содержать хотя бы один элемент. Кстати, упорядоченность исходного списка не имеет значения.

Comment: большое спасибо! подскажите пожалуйста как можно этот результат получить с помощью методов кластеризации. Алгоритмы действия понятны, проблема заключается в реализации именно в питоне. Подскажите пожалуйста где можно рассмотреть подобные примеры

Comment: @Амир, в комментариях к вопросу есть ссылка. Смотрите там, изучайте модуль `itertools`. Я его, к сожалению, практически не знаю. Реализация дана именно на питоне.

Answer (score 2):

С использованием Numpy:

```
In [32]: a = np.array([11,12,13,15,16,17,19])

In [33]: np.split(a, np.where(np.diff(a) != 1)[0]+1)
Out[33]: [array([11, 12, 13]), array([15, 16, 17]), array([19])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
In [186]: def Ex(array):
     ...:     result = [[array[0]]]
     ...:     for i, j in enumerate(array[1:], 1):
     ...:         if j - array[i-1] == 1:
     ...:             result[-1].append(j)
     ...:         else:
     ...:             result.append([j])
     ...:     return result
```

Результат:

```
In [179]: Ex(lst)
Out[179]: [[11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17], [19]]
```

Решение похоже на @andy.37, но алгоритм устроен немного иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Также возможно через рекурсию, не очевидный с первого взгляда, но красивый алгоритм.

```
def task(x, y, z=list()):
    """
    :param x: входной список возрастающих элементов, type: list
    :param y: если разница между элементами больше y, то они попадут в разные группы, type: int
    :param z: список в который будут собираться группы, type: list
    :return: возвращает группы элементов списком списков, type: list
    >>> task([11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19], 1)
    [[11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17], [19]]
    >>> task([11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19], 1, [[8, 9]])
    [[8, 9], [11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17], [19]]
    """
    t = list()
    for i in x:
        if len(x) - x.index(i) == 1:
            t.append(i)
            z.append(t)
            break
        else:
            if x[x.index(i) + 1] - i <= y:
                t.append(i)
            else:
                t.append(i)
                z.append(t)
                task(x[x.index(i) + 1:], y, z)
                break
    return z
```

Можно еще заменить break на while, сжать append - вообще хорошо будет.

Comment: Логика интересная, но много чего можно сократить и улучшить. Но плюса заслуживает :)